# Web-resources from Javascript

Tags: handlebars.js, jira-plugin, webresource

I need to get handlebars templates in Javascript. 
So I create template file in tpl folder and wrote such line in ML:

```
<resource type="download" name="tpl/" location="/tpl"/>
```

if I put some image to this folder I can to get it from CSS:

```
.css
 {
background: url(tpl/image.png);
}
```

if I want to get this image from js `AJS.$("css").css("background", "url(tpl/image.png)")` I have the error - file not found;

image file is for example.. In real I need to get template

```
 AJS.$.ajax({
                    url: "tpl/backlog_coll.handlebars",
                    cache: true,
                    success: function(data) {
                        source    = data;
                        template  = Handlebars.compile(source);
                        $('#backlog_coll').html(template);
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do that

I will write a function in a generally accessible js file (lets call it Global.js for now) as shown below

GLOBAL.JS

```
function fnGetTemplate(strName) {
if (Handlebars.templates === undefined || Handlebars.templates[strName] === undefined) {
$.ajax({
   url : "tpl" + strName + ".handlebars",
   success : function(data) {
       if (Handlebars.templates === undefined) {
           Handlebars.templates = {};
       }
       Handlebars.templates[strName] = Handlebars.compile(data);
   },
   async : false
 });
}
return Handlebars.templates[strName];
}
```

This is assuming I have the handlebars js library (something like handlebars-v1.3.0.js) referred to appropriately.

Then inside the View where I need the template to show up, I would declare the template as shown below

```
template: fnGetTemplate("backlog_coll");
```

Inside the render function of my view I would call this template supplying the needed data as show below

```
render: function() {
    this.$el.html(this.template(data));
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This method do not found templates too. it should be like `/jira/s/ru_RU-g6ghuq/773/3/1.0-SNAPSHOT/_/download/resources/com.swan.agile.swan-agile:swan-agile-scrumboard/tpl/" + strName + ".handlebars `

Comment: Actually in the example I hardcoded the path as "tpl" just for ease of explanation. In reality, you should take it out as a variable value so that you can dynamically populate the path of that template, as shown below

    function fnGetTemplate(strPath, strName) {
    if (Handlebars.templates === undefined ||       
     Handlebars.templates[strName] === undefined) {
     $.ajax({
         url : strPath + strName + ".handlebars",

and call it as 
    template: fnGetTemplate(strPath, strName);